# SQL Server stored procedure inserting duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with column `GetDup` and I'd like to the duplicate records based on the value of this column. For example, if value on is 1 in `GetDup`, then duplicate the record once. If value in the column is 2, then duplicate the record twice and so on and the statement has to be in looping statement.

What will be a good way to write a stored procedures for this? Please help.

Input:

```
+--------+--------------+---------------+
| Getdup | CustomerName | CustomerAdd   |
+--------+--------------+---------------+
|      1 | John         | 123 SomeWhere |
|      2 | Bob          | 987 SomeWhere |
+--------+--------------+---------------+
```

What I want:

```
+--------+--------------+---------------+
| Getdup | CustomerName | CustomerAdd   |
+--------+--------------+---------------+
|      1 | John         | 123 SomeWhere |
|      1 | John         | 123 SomeWhere |
|      2 | Bob          | 987 SomeWhere |
|      2 | Bob          | 987 SomeWhere |
|      2 | Bob          | 987 SomeWhere |
+--------+--------------+---------------+
```

[picture of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbjTR.jpg)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results in table form

Comment: sample data is attached

Comment: I would also question why you want to reinsert duplicated records into your table. What is the end-goal?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer #2 After Clarification**

Number Table to the Rescue!

The number table in my example (or tally table, if you want to call it that), is both temporary and very small. To make it bigger, just add more values to `z` and add more `CROSS JOIN`s. In my opinion, a number table and a calendar table are both things that should be in every database you have. They are extremely useful.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5723e/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ( Getdup int, CustomerName varchar(10), CustomerAdd varchar(20) ) ;

INSERT INTO mytable (Getdup, CustomerName, CustomerAdd)
VALUES (1,'John','123 SomeWhere'), (2,'Bob','987 SomeWhere')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH z AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM ( VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0) ) v(x)
)
, numTable AS (
  SELECT num 
  FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY z1.x)-1 num 
    FROM z z1 
    CROSS JOIN z z2 
  ) s1
)
SELECT t1.Getdup, t1.CustomerName, t1.CustomerAdd
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN numTable ON t1.getdup >= numTable.num
ORDER BY CustomerName, CustomerAdd
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5723e/1/0)**:

```
| Getdup | CustomerName |   CustomerAdd |
|--------|--------------|---------------|
|      2 |          Bob | 987 SomeWhere |
|      2 |          Bob | 987 SomeWhere |
|      2 |          Bob | 987 SomeWhere |
|      1 |         John | 123 SomeWhere |
|      1 |         John | 123 SomeWhere |
```

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

**EDIT:** After further clarification of the problem, this won't duplicate rows, this will only duplicate the data in a column.

Something like one of these might work.

**T-SQL**

```
SELECT replicate(mycolumn,getdup) AS x
FROM mytable
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT repeat(mycolumn,getdup) AS x
FROM mytable
```

**Oracle SQL**

```
SELECT rpad(mycolumn,getdup*length(mycolumn),mycolumn) AS x
FROM mytable
```

**PostgreSQL**

```
SELECT repeat(mycolumn,getdup+1) AS x
FROM mytable
```

If you can provide more details for exactly what you want and what you're working with, we might be able to help you better.

**NOTE 2:** Depending on what you need, you may need to do some math magic. You say above if `GetDup` is 1 then you want one duplicate. If that means that your output should be ``` GetDup``GetDup ```, then you'll want to add one in the `repeat()`,`replicate()` or `rpad()` functions.   ie `replicate(mycolumn,getdup+1)`. Oracle SQL will be a little different, since it uses `rpad()`.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9e0b4/1   <<< This includes the +1 to `mycolumn` that it _seems_ like you're asking for.

Comment: How this will relate with the o/p ??

Comment: @YogeshSharma My original answer was before OP clarified. I've updated my answer to use a tally table to get rows instead of a replicated column.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select t.dup, . . .
      from t
      union all
      select cte.dup - 1, . . .
      from cte
      where cte.dup > 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Of course, not all databases support recursive CTEs (and the `recursive` keyword is not used in some of them).

Answer (score 0):

So, you want *recursive* solution :

```
with t as (
    select Getdup, CustomerName, CustomerAdd, 0 as id
    from table
    union all
    select Getdup, CustomerName, CustomerAdd, id + 1
    from t
    where id < getdup
)
insert into table (col1, col2, col3)
select Getdup, CustomerName, CustomerAdd
from t
order by getdup
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: Yogesh. .  Thanks for your answer,   using your logic,  How can I physically insert the records to the table?

Comment: @JongLee. . . Use `INSERT INTO. . ` statement.

Comment: @JongLee. . . If you are inserting record in existing table then start with 1 as id.

Comment: Thank you so much..    Insert into..  and starting id with 1 worked.   That was what I wanted.     Once Side question.   the actual table that work with right now has too many columns.   Is there way to use "*"  instead of specifying the actual column name for each.

Comment: @JongLee. . . Of course you can use `select *` instead.

Comment: with t as (
    select *,  1 as id
    from [dbo].[Customer]
    union all
    select *, id + 1
    from t
    where id < getdup
)
--insert into [dbo].[Customer]
select * 
from t
order by getdup
option (maxrecursion 0);         tried this but getting error message  "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists"

Comment: @JongLee. . . I meant use `*` instead while inserting the values, . .  `recursive` requires explicit column names and that is one time only.

Comment: I would recommend against `SELECT *`. There is a high potential to insert unintended data into your table. I'd stick with the explicit column names.